# How to get only values from this json code?

Tags: json, jq

I want to list all values in form of string `*.md` no matter where they occur. How to achieve this in `jq`

```
[
  {
    "Home Page": "index.md"
  },
  {
    "Chapters": [
      {
        "Foreword": "Aforeword.md"
      },
      {
        "Chap1": "ch001.md"
      },
      {
        "Chap2": "ch002.md"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please specify the question more precisely. See in particular stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Are you looking for all key values that are strings ending in ".md", no matter where they occur?

Comment: @peak Yes. This is what is want.  I modified question based upon your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that scans for all *.md strings:

```
jq -r '.. | strings | select(endswith(".md"))'
```

Output:

```
index.md
Aforeword.md
ch001.md
ch002.md
```

If you only want to check for strings that occur as key values:

```
.. | objects | .[] | strings | select( endswith(".md"))
```

You might want to modify the selection criterion to allow for ".MD", etc. So you might want to use `test("\\.md$"; "i")`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - Please undelete your answer!  It is worthwhile and instructive.